# Injecting Code to format all columns as text to retain leading zeros from CSVs

Tags: vba, excel

So here is 1 part of a 3 part macro that lets you browse to a folder and consolidate/transpose/retain header of a bunch of .csv files.  The problem we have is where to inject some code so that routing and account numbers are formatted as text and retain their leading zeros.  If the easiest solution is to just format the entire sheet as text, that would work for us...whatever it takes without having to go into specifics since this info wont always be in the same column.

Thanks in advance!

```
Option Explicit

'Set a public constant variable
Public Const DNL As String = vbNewLine & vbNewLine

Sub ImportData()

'Declare all variables
Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet
Dim wbX As Workbook, wsX As Worksheet
Dim i As Long, iRow As Long, iFileNum As Long, sMsg As String
Dim vFolder As Variant, sSubFolder As String, sFileName As String
Dim bOpen As Boolean

'Turn off some application-level events to improve code efficiency
Call TOGGLEEVENTS(False)

'Have the user choose the folder
vFolder = BrowseForFolder()

'Exit if nothing was chosen, variable will be False
If vFolder = False Then Exit Sub

'Check if this is what the user wants to do, confirm with a message box, exit if no
sMsg = "Are you sure you want to import data from this folder:"
sMsg = sMsg & DNL & vFolder
If MsgBox(sMsg, vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "ARE YOU SURE?") <> vbYes Then Exit Sub

'Set sub-folder as variable for save name at end of routine
sSubFolder = Right(vFolder, Len(vFolder) - InStrRev(vFolder, Application.PathSeparator))

'Set destination file with one worksheet
Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
Set ws = wb.Sheets(1)

'This will be the row to start data on, to incriment in loop
iRow = 2

'Loop through files in folder
sFileName = Dir$(vFolder & "\")
Do Until sFileName = ""

    'Check that the file pattern matches what you want, i.e. 12.16.00.xls
    If sFileName Like "*.csv" Then '### set file extension here

        'Check to see if the file is open
        'If file is open, set as variable, if not, open and set as variable
        If ISWBOPEN(sFileName) = True Then
            Set wbX = Workbooks(sFileName)
            bOpen = True
        Else
            Set wbX = Workbooks.Open(vFolder & "\" & sFileName)
            bOpen = False
        End If

        'Set first sheet in target workbok as worksheet variable, from which to mine data
        Set wsX = wbX.Sheets(1)

        'Get last row from column A (range for copy/pasting)
        i = wsX.Cells(wsX.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

        'Check if a file has been added, if not add headers (frequency)
        If iFileNum = 0 Then
            ws.Range("B1", ws.Cells(1, i + 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(wsX.Range("A1:A" & i))
        End If

        'Add data
        ws.Range("B" & iRow, ws.Cells(iRow, i + 1)).Value = Application.Transpose(wsX.Range("B1:B" & i))

        'Add file name to column A
        ws.Range("A" & iRow).Value = "'" & Left$(sFileName, Len(sFileName) - 4)

        'Incriment variable values
        iRow = iRow + 1
        iFileNum = iFileNum + 1

        'If file was closed to start with, clean up and close it
        If bOpen = False Then wbX.Close SaveChanges:=False

    End If

    'Get next file name
    sFileName = Dir$()
Loop

'Check if file name to save exists
If Dir$(vFolder & "\" & sSubFolder & ".xls", vbNormal) = "" Then
    wb.SaveAs vFolder & "\" & sSubFolder & ".xls"
    MsgBox "Complete!", vbOKOnly
Else
    MsgBox "File already exists!  File is NOT saved!", vbInformation, "COMPLETE!"
End If

'Reset events back to application defaults
Call TOGGLEEVENTS(True)

End Sub
```

Comment: For reference the rest of the code is on this page https://forums.techguy.org/threads/importing-multiple-csv-files-and-transposing-data.896903/

Comment: What I do is set the `NumberFormat` before importing the data. If all of the data in the column is the same type, then before you copy the data, add the line `ws.Range("B" & iRow, ws.Cells(iRow, i + 1)).NumberFormat = wsX.Range("B1").NumberFormat` If you have different types in the CSV file and you are fine just bringing it all over as text, you can just add the line to set the number format right before Add Data in the same way.

Comment: It seems like I would have to know specifically which column the data is in and this is subject to change since the multiple applications we receive don't always have the accounting/routing numbers in the same column.  I'd rather just get the functionality of "text to Columns" except on a massive scale as is shown in this macro.  Maybe I'm misinterpreting your response.

Comment: The point with that line of code is that it won't matter - it will mirror the NumberFormat that the CSV uses on a column by column basis, so it should come over with leading zero's if it is stored as text in the CSV. I run into this all the time - my coworker had 50 or so lines of code to sort out what the number format should be ... I just copy the number format from the cells we are importing and we don't have issues anymore.

Comment: So where would you put this line of code? after " 'add data " ?

Comment: Before Add Data - give it a shot and let me know if it works for you. Note that if there are some cells stored as Numbers and some cells stored as text, you will need to loop through the cells to assign the proper number format - this will probably have some associated overhead but is also doable.

Comment: Yeah this didn't seem to work

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - since I can't see your data, I can't tell if B1 is the correct number format (that's the cell I chose in the code I gave you). Basically what I'm getting at is this: The CSV will have that value stored as Text, when you copy the VALUE ONLY, excel will try to figure out what it is and change it - this is why you lose leading zero's. To fix this, copy the number format that the CSV uses AND the values. Downside is you can't transpose numberformats.so you will have to loop through the cells.

Comment: To make all the data come over as "Text", you can use `ws.Range("B" & iRow, ws.Cells(iRow, i + 1)).NumberFormat = "@"` before Add Data. If you want to set the NumberFormat to the same numberformat that is listed on the CSV, look at the code I posted below. You will need to pull the data differently instead of just using `Application.Transpose` because sadly you can't transpose numberformats and assign properties of cells in that way - you have to do it on a cell by cell basis if you have mixed data in your column. My original one-liner will work if the first piece of data is stored as text.